# -bash: command not found appears every time

Tags: macos, terminal, bash

I just recently discovered what terminal was. I started using it today and every time I try a command (like shh) it says that the command was not found. I was instructed to type in `echo $PATH` and this is what I got

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

How can I fix this? I know mostly nothing about terminal or how to use it.

Comment: You have an error in your `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` file. Check out those files to solve it.

Comment: Where can I find those files? (Im sorry, I know nothing about this kind of stuff)

Comment: Must exists in your home directory (ej. `/home/username/.bash_profile`).

Comment: Your $PATH looks good. There's no such command as 'shh,' however, so entering it on the command line would be expected to return an error message. What other commands have given you trouble?

Comment: It occurs to me that I would be better able to help you if, in addition to  a list of the other commands that can't be found, you could also provide a description of any other steps you have taken to fix the problem. The advice to check your $PATH was a good first step--did you receive any other suggestions from the same source?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if the command you want is ssh , not shh.  Are you trying to connect to another computer? As Doc G points out, your PATH looks fine.

Comment: You're probably right, Adrian. I had the same thought about 'shh' being a typo for 'ssh.' Myranda's stated complaint, though, is not "every time I try the command shh it says that the command was not found," but that "every time I try a command (like shh) it says that the command was not found." As her successful invocation of /bin/echo indicates, it clearly is not the case that *every* command fails. A listing of the other failed commands should provide a more pertinent starting point from which to proceed, as opposed to tackling them one at a time.